# play audio using base64 string in react native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios, react-native-fs, react-native-sound

I have **encoded** audio in **base64** string using **react-native-fs**. Now I want to **decode** **base64** string back to audio format and play in **react-native**.

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const [audioBase64,setAudioBase64]=React.useState(null)

RNFS.readFile(audioPath,"base64").then((res)=>setAudioBase64(res))
```

Now my base64 string is saved in audioPath.

By the way for playing sound, I am using **react-native-sound** and I couldn't find any format to play sound in react-native-sound using base64 data.

If anyone has experienced this and resolve the issue then kindly do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

i some how want to do something similar,
i think first we need to write string base 64 and after that play it
like below:

```
const path = '${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${attachment}.aac';
RNFS.writeFile(path, yourBase64String, 'base64').then(() => playSound())
const playSound = () => {
const sound = new Sound(path, '', () => callback(sound))
}
const callback = () => sound.play(successCallback)
```